A pot was filled completely with water, and then the pot was tilted at an angle of $45$ degrees. Calculate the volume of water that remained in.
A cylinder-shaped pot with base radius $R$ and height $H$ was filled completely with water, and then the pot was tilted at an angle of $45$ degrees so that some of the water spilled out. Calculate the volume of water that remained in the pot. Assume that: $R \leq H \leq 2R$.
(Initially I made a mistake, had to correct the picture)

In that case I can't even use polar coordinates. I looked up cylindrical wedge on Wolfram, as suggested by David K. As I understand, in my case, we can't assume that the plane passing cutting the cylinder is going through a diameter of the base.
We can look at the walls of the blue solid (cylindrical wedge) and observe that:
the value of $z$ in a given point at the wall $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ changes based solely on $x$ (it doesn't depend on $y$) so we can describe that dependency with a linear equation:
$$z = -x +b$$
We know that a point $(-R,H)$ belongs in that equation, so:
$H = -(-R) +b \iff b = H - R$
So we have that:
$$z = -x + H - R$$
Similarly, value of $y$ in a given point at the wall $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ changes based solely on $x$ (it doesn't depend on $z$) so we can describe that dependency with an equation of a circle:
$$y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$$
Now, we need to integrate over those $3$ dimensions described with x and dependencies on x:
$$V = \int_{-R}^{H-R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} \int_{0}^{-x + H - R}  1 \ dz \ dy \ dx$$
$$V = \int_{-R}^{H-R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}  -x + H - R \ dy \ dx$$
$$V = \int_{-R}^{H-R} (-x + H - R)\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} \ dx$$
... and it's some monstrosity.

I think you are doing too much work. $45^\circ$ is special in some way. Also, just from dimensional analysis alone it cannot be correct. It is volume not area.

Seems like overkill.  "Obviously" the white half of the missing water is equal to the lower blue triangle.  If course we have to prove that.  But that's easy and won't require such complicated integrals.

I get $\pi R^2(H-{R \over 2})$.

There are some mistakes. Note that your final volume has units of length squared instead of length cubed. It all starts at the equation of the plane, where you should get $b=H-R$

The diagram is contradicted by the condition $H\leq 2R$. This makes the problem considerably more difficult.

Ok, thank you for comments! I will try to get my solution right for the case described by the picture, by avoiding the mistake shown by @Andrei. Then I will make another picture to match the question, as mentioned by David K. I will use integrals (and not use the 45* special case) because I want to do that that way.

Btw, if anybody out here is proficient in real analysis (manifolds) - can you have look at my other question? I am trying to get some understanding in those topics and currently looking for someone to verify my answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4908880/show-that-an-image-of-transformation-is-a-manifold-solution-verification-sear

@copper.hat are you sure that it souldn't be $\pi R^2 (H-R)$? I edited my original question and that is the result I get now.

The problem that arises when $H<2R$ is that when you consider all $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and all $r$ from $0$ to $R,$ you encounter the case where $r\cos\theta > H-R.$
And in that case, the integrand in your integral is negative. But the height of water in the pot can never be negative.
In particular, when $H=R$ (the minimum value of $H$), your formula $\pi R^2(H - R)$ gives the result zero, although obviously there is a positive amount of water in the pot. The error is due to all the “negative volume” that your integral includes.
When $H<2R$ you have a cylindrical wedge. This requires a different integral.
The integral is easier to set up in Cartesian coordinates than polar coordinates.

So for the first case, it's correct and for the second one I need a whole other approach?

Yes, and as you saw when you worked it out, it’s much uglier than the case $H\geq 2R.$

@thefool I thnk you're probably stuck with integration in case 2. Best of luck.

From your sketch directly using symmetry when
$$~(H \geq 2R \ge R),~~  V= \pi R^2(H-R)\text{ at centre/mid height} ~ $$
$$\text{ + some Volume of  cylindrical wedge red  - same Volume of  cylindrical wedge blue } = \pi R^2(H-R)~$$

Why not keep simple things simple?

You seem to be subtracting an area from a volume, but you've corrected it by getting the algebra wrong. But it doesn't work - see @DavidK's comment.

No, why only $(H-R/2)$? Take a closer look to the sketch. Imagine after tilting to rotate the cylinder back, the liquids's level will be at $H-R$, thus the remaining $V=\pi R^2(H-R)$.

@m-stgt The diagram is wrong. The surface should be truncated by the base. Narasimham has reversed one of the inequalities. With the reversal you're correct, the missing water should be $\frac{1}{2}\pi R^22R$.

@Narasimham I edited my original question to make up for the mistake with the picture. However, I get different result (is mine wrong?). Also, in your solution, there's something wrong with powers of $R$.

@MartinRattigan -- After the edit of OP my solution is only valid for case 1.

@m-stgt Of course. Case 2 is a little more complicated.

@MartinRattigan -- Case 2 was solved recently on this site, but I have not found it again yet, sorry.

@m-stgt David K's link gives the solution. I got as far as calculating the area of the circular segments parallel to the base with a view to integrating along the axis then decided it was taking too long. I was faster at these things when I was at school.

Typo my bad, updated with simple sketch.
